# Cannot get a like Button

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

i just try to get a like & share button on my website with the code from the generator:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=278654312150503";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

......

......

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://wwww.friendsmap.info" data-send="true" data-layout="box_count" data-width="70" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Firebug said to me "Invalid ApplicationID"
But the appID is the same like my facebook developer shows it

What can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me, possible problem could be that you activated the sandbox mode in the developer settings. But you do have an error in the URL: http://wwww.friendsmap.info > 4 w´s

Also check the Website URL in the developer settings, maybe you got it wrong there too.